# Owl carousel not working with loop in vuejs and axios

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

I am using vue in my existing codeigniter project by including via CDN.
i am having problem in using owl carousel. i fetched data using axios and populated in div using v-for method. but it seems owl carousel not working.

I have also added screenshot of what i am facing.

here is the script part

```
     <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
new Vue({
            el: '#offerstab',
            data () {
                return {
                   touroffers: [],
                   caroffers: [],
                   hoteloffers: [],
                   cruiseoffers: [],
                   flightoffers: [],
                }
            },

            methods: {
                getOffers () {
                axios
                .get('https://www.happyvoyaging.com/api/offers/listcustom',{
                    params: {
                      category: ['tours','flight','cars','cruise','rail','hotel']
                    }
                })

                .then(res => (this.touroffers = res.data.off_tours,this.caroffers = res.data.off_cars,this.hoteloffers = res.data.off_hotels,this.cruiseoffers = res.data.off_cruises,this.flightoffers = res.data.off_flights))
            },
            },

            mounted() {
               this.getOffers();
             },
            })
</script>
```

this is my html part where i want owl carousel to be initiated.

```
<div id="offerstab">
            <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel-nav-dark" data-items="3" data-loop="true" data-nav="true">
              
              <div v-for="touroffer in touroffers" class="theme-inline-slider-item">
                <div class="banner _h-33vh _br-5 banner-">
                  <div class="banner-bg" v-bind:style="`background-image:url('${touroffer.thumbnail}');`"></div>
                  <div class="banner-mask banner-mask-half"></div>
                  <a class="banner-link" href="#"></a>
                  <div class="banner-caption _ta-c banner-caption-bottom">
                    <h5 class="banner-title _tt-uc">{{ touroffer.title }}5</h5>
                    <p class="banner-subtitle">Top deals from most visited cities</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

[this is how its looking, it should show 3 columns here but it is showing one below another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl6PA.jpg)

[This is what i expect, as it works well with static code without vue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0quA.png)

[This is data in touroffers after axioscall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnYw0.png)

Comment: Since you are retrieving your data asynchronously, try ```<div v-if="touroffers.length" class="owl-carousel ...>```

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried it now and now owl carousel is not displaying the div, i mean i cannot see any content, when inspecting, i can see the loop there and owl carousel class got set to display:none

Comment: Confirm that ```touroffers``` contains data after the axios call.  And also try ```<div v-if="touroffers.length > 0" ...>```.

Comment: Hi Tim, I added a screenshot in question, you can see there is data in touroffers, because if it wasn't there, it wouldn't have looped, but loop is working fine, it is creating the data in div, but owl carousel is not working here.

Comment: I tried <div v-if="touroffers.length > 0" ...> , still its not working, it is somehow setting class owlcarousel {display : none }, when i use your code.

Comment: I know that v-if works in general.  I haven't used Owl Carousel.  At this point, I would try to just get a basic owl carousel working with hard coded data.  Once you can get it to display, try using your app data again.

Comment: The div outside your owl-carousel has some style aplied to it?  Try removing it. Also if I reade the documentation correctly, you should call the plugin after you received data from axios. ```$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});```

Comment: Hi Mael, There is no style applied outside of my owl carousel. I have tried your answer already and it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Hi @Tim I tried to hardcode data and it seems to be working, but when i switch it back to fetch same data from api, it throw the same issue. i think, there is some issue with axios and owl carousel, owl carousel is not getting initiated properly after axios call. and i am not able to understand, how to solve this issue.

Comment: Hey @vinaythakur I'm currently between jobs, so I'm taking some time to build a Vue 2 CLI app that uses Owl Carousel (I'm a newbie to Owl).  I have a very basic initial carousel rendering.  If I get it working with data pulled from an API, I plan to post it in an answer.  In the meantime, let me know if you get yours working.

Comment: @vinaythakur I was able to get my Vue 2 w/CLI sample app working locally with hard coded data, as you were, but not when using 'v-for' and axios data.  Probably related to jQuery, which I don't use much anymore, and try to avoid importing it into my Vue apps.  At this point I am going to move on.  Since I use Bootstrap 4, I may try to get the Bootstrap carousel working as a learning exercise.  Also, I did a quick search and found [Carousels Made with Vue](https://madewithvuejs.com/carousels).  I haven't used any of them, but if you can't get Owl working, possibly an alternative.